# Can we use .NET System.Windows.Forms.Timer to replace Excel VBA Application.onTime?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, timer

We are asked not to use Application.OnTime again by our client. That's our pre-condition, sorry it is out of our control.

But since we need run some tasks periodically, we need to find an alternative timer. We already try System.Timers.Timer but it has some problems for Microsoft Excel. The reason is that Microsoft Excel does not support multiple threads but System.timers.timer use multiple thread.

So now we want to try System.Windows.Forms.Timer. This timer use windows message pump and it seems it should work for Microsoft Excel. We can use System.Windows.Forms.Timer in C# and then raise an event to VBA periodically.

From Kenny Kerr's article of http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Rtd3, it seems our idea is fine. But could someone dig deeper and figure out how System.Windows.Forms.Timer works and answer why it work or not from underlying theory.

Comment: This sounds _exactly_ like you're asking someone else to do your research for you.

Comment: Actually I did a lot of research but I still did not get the answer.

Comment: And you want someone else to "dig deeper and figure out how System.Windows.Forms.Timer works"

Comment: If you're using VBA, the Application.OnTime is the way to go. What's your client's objection to it? It would help to know what it is that you're *actually* trying to accomplish. As it is, this is a very poorly formed question.

Comment: right. I googled some days, I know System.windows.Forms.Timer use windows message pump but I am still not sure whether it works for Excel. I tried and it seems works but I am still not sure. I need someone support me from underlying theory.

Comment: To RubberDuck, Thanks for your question. he demand us so it is out of our control. we need an alterative timer.

Comment: Actually there is a bug in Application.Ontimer. When user add some names and tables to excel, the name list in the formula bar can be long. So user many need some time to choose one name. If applicatoin.ontime is triggered when user is selecting, the name list will disappear so use have to choose it again. That's the reason we get the demand

Comment: I recommend that you ask how to fix that problem instead. At the end of the day, the client doesn't care what timer you use. They care that the program doesn't steal the focus away while the user is doing something.

Comment: that's good idea. Thanks.   
And do you have any idea about replacing application.ontime with windows.forms.timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the timer in previous reply works and is our currently solution.
Now we want to move this solution to C#.

And now I confirmed that System.Windows.Forms.Timer can work with excel because it is regiested in a hidden form to do window message loop. So the thread is always same with the excel main thread. then it works in excel.

You can use GetCurrentThreadId API to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a VBA application, why would you want to use .NET APIs?  Unless you are already doing so for other reasons, e.g. it's using VSTO.

An alternative to using Application.OnTime without using .NET would be to use the Win32 API (SetTimer / KillTimer).

Here's an extract of some code to get you started (it's not a complete working sample):

```
Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
    ByVal uElapse As Long, ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Private m_TimerID As Long

Private Sub StartTimer()
    m_TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 100&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Private Sub EndTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    KillTimer 0&, m_TimerID
End Sub

Private Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

    EndTimer

    ... do your stuff here.  Call StartTimer to start the timer again if desired
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. We already try this way. And now our team are discussing about the system.windows.forms.time. we want to know it is possible to replace application.ontime